# Implementation for Boolean operations on polygons like union, intersections, contains?

Tags: geometry, ogr, shapely, jts-topology-suite

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons#Algorithms

I wish to understand how are Boolean operations on polygons implemented in GIS related geometry libraries. I've tried to go deeper into Shapely, OGR, JTS in that chronology. I believe that the former is a port of the latter, in all the three libraries. I advanced until [here](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/9d4097312d68cb8f9ae591bec69ce3b403e41e98/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/geom/prep/AbstractPreparedPolygonContains.java), and got stuck. It seemed to me that [this](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/9d4097312d68cb8f9ae591bec69ce3b403e41e98/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/geom/prep/AbstractPreparedPolygonContains.java#L232) function is called recursively (I'm sure I'm wrong here).

Could anyone here who already has contributed to any of the libraries explain?

Comment: I'd classify these as Venn diagrams (set operations) more than Boolean operations, though the algebra and calculus of these operations were formally defined by Clementini,  et. al.